# How to enable async support in a Springboot application packaged and deployed as WAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, war, servlet-3.0

The following REST endpoint shown below works as expected when my SpringBoot application is run from an executable JAR. That is, it returns the text "My test response" to the client.  However, when I package the same application as a WAR and deploy to Tomcat (8.0.29) it throws the following exception:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.

```
package my.rest.controllers;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBody;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/file")
public class FileContentRestController {

static final int BUFFER = 2048;

@RequestMapping(value = "/content", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public StreamingResponseBody getFileContent(HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        final InputStream portalFileStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("My test response".getBytes());
        return (OutputStream outputStream) -> {
            int n;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while ((n = portalFileStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
            portalFileStream.close();
        };

}

}
```

My understanding from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1665) and elsewhere is that SpringBoot enables async support on all the filters and servlets registered by SpringBoot.  It would certainly seems to be the case when run from a standalone JAR with the embedded Tomcat container.

**How can I ensure async support is enabled when deploying as a WAR?**

My SpringBoot application is configured thus:

```
package my;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.springframework.boot.Banner;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MyRestApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MyRestApp.class).bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    }

}
```

with MVC configured thus:

```
package my;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.AsyncSupportConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAsync
public class MyMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(-1);
        configurer.setTaskExecutor(asyncTaskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("SpringAsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Finally, the application is built and packaged using Maven with the following POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-rest-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>my-rest-app</name>
    <description></description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5):

Well the exception you parsed says it all:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.

Thus you need to enable it either in your web.xml or (and because you are using a spring-boot application) you have to configure a specific bean.

Maybe this code snippet for your AppConfig would help

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DispatcherServlet(), "/");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: a `springboot` app probably has no `web.xml` file

Comment: What this appears to do is create a dispatcher servlet configured with an external XML file, so I get : java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml]
.

Comment: My understanding is that SpringBoot's Auto configuration creates a default dispatcher servlet and sets AsyncSupported to true by default.  The question is why does the application behave differently when deployed as a WAR to an external Tomact container, compared with when deployed as an executable JAR with an embedded Tomcat container?

Comment: Well if you run it as s fat jar Spring uses an embedded Tomcat and configures it the way it is needed by your beans. But of you build a war and deploy it into an external Tomcat, I assume Spring could not configure all parts of the external app server.

Comment: Registering my own dispatcherServlet as suggested and supplying the required WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @GarethHughes did you solved this? I have the same issue here

Comment: Yes, see my solution dated Nov 24 '17 at 13:31 below.

Answer (score 4):

My external Tomcat instance was the one installed and configured with NetBeans.  In the %CATALINA_BASE%\conf folder there is a web.xml that applies to all applications deployed to the server.  In there was a filter named HTTPMonitorFilter which did not support async requests.  Adding true to that filter definition solved my problem.

Comment: Very nice! This was absolutely the case. Someone added custom filters to Tomcat's `conf/web.xml` and it took me forever to find that!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my springboot application.

```
Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async......
```

I just add

> @WebFilter(asyncSupported = true)

in my filters. The default is false:

> /**
>        *   Declares whether the filter supports asynchronous operation mode.
>        *
>        *   @see javax.servlet.ServletRequest#startAsync
>        *   @see javax.servlet.ServletRequest#startAsync(ServletRequest,
>        *   ServletResponse)
>        */
>        boolean asyncSupported() default false;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Running the app with in an embedded tomcat server ( with maven-tomcat7-plugin ) works fine, no errors. Deployed to an external tomcat server (the spring boot app packaged as a .WAR) :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing. This is done in Java code using the Servlet API or by adding "true" to servlet and filter declarations in web.xml.

This is the only solution that worked for me. I had to create the file src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml with the following contents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <filter>
            <filter-name>cacheControlFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>xxx.yourimplementation.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
            <async-supported>true</async-supported>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>css,html,js</param-name>
                <param-value>cache-control=1800,edge-control=1800</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>ajax,htm</param-name>
                <param-value>cache-control=0,edge-control=0</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>doc,gif,ico,jpe,jpeg,jpg,pdf,png,swf</param-name>
                <param-value>cache-control=1800,edge-control=7200</param-value>
            </init-param>
    </filter>

</webapp>
```

This fixed the problem for me. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use spring boot SimpleBeanPropertyFilter to resolve it
Use the below link to find git repo and get an idea
May help:-

Let's see the entity class:

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
//this JasonFilter annotation was required
    @JsonFilter("Employee")
    public class Employee {
        Integer id;
    
        String name;
        String mobile;
        String land;
        String email;
        String address;
    //getter and setter required
    }
```

Now see the controller class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();

    private void setEmployee(){

        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        Employee employee2 = new Employee();

        //employee :- take total value from entity ("This can be done using getOne()")
        //if need to filter List<> need create for lop until list.length

        employee1.id = 1;
        employee1.name = "Lalith";
        employee1.email = "asakahata****@gmail.com";
        employee1.mobile = "07723******";
        employee1.land = "01231****";
        employee1.address = "Colombo 8";

        employee2.id = 2;
        employee2.name = "Lalith1";
        employee2.email = "asakahata*1***@gmail.com";
        employee2.mobile = "07723***1***";
        employee2.land = "01231**1**";
        employee2.address = "Colombo 81";

        employee.add(employee1);
        employee.add(employee2);
    }


        //request few parameter from entity
        @GetMapping("/requestFilterValueFromEntity")
        public MappingJacksonValue filterParameter(){
            setEmployee();

    //Create new mapping jackson value and set it to which was need to filter

            MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(employee);

            //simpleBeanPropertyFilter :-  need to give any id to addFilter method and created filter which was mentioned what parameter's necessary to provide
      SimpleBeanPropertyFilter simpleBeanPropertyFilter =  SimpleBeanPropertyFilter
                                                .filterOutAllExcept("id","name","email");
            //filters :-  set front end required value to before filter

            FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                                .addFilter("Employee", simpleBeanPropertyFilter);
            //Employee :- need to annotate relevant class with JosonFilter  {@JsonFilter("Employee") }
            mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);

            return mappingJacksonValue;
        }
    }
```

> use the below repository to see the example

**[Github Repository](https://github.com/Lalith90/spring_parameter_filtering)**